# How to reduce time while converting j2k image to bitmap using MagickImage dll?

Tags: c#, winforms, imagemagick

I am loading j2k images(by converting into `Bitmap`) using `MagickImage.dll` in c#.

available here.
[MagickImage.dll](https://magick.codeplex.com/releases/view/117276)

sample code of loading j2k image in c# is :

```
 MagickImage image = new MagickImage(fileName);
  Bitmap bitmap= image.ToBitmap();
  pictureBox.Image=bitmap;
```

It is loading properly but taking a long time for e.g. 10-12 seconds per image. Can anybody tell how to reduce the time while converting image to Bitmap?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you measure which operation is taking long? Feel free to start a topic here: https://magick.codeplex.com/discussions. Please include one of your images.

Comment: I have posted my question on discussion forum. Sorry,I can't include images here but i have 30 j2k images of size 73.9 kb each and folder size is 2.12 mb.I am loading all images at one time it is taking near about 2 minutes and for one image it is taking near about 40 seconds.